# Native sharing menu in Trigger.io Forge

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to access the native sharing menu from a Trigger.io app? That is, the menu that typically presents all the compatible apps the user has on their phone to which they could share something from within the open app?

Comment: I'd love to see something like that as well!

Comment: This isn't implemented yet - no: with the recent improvements to native plugins which deal with files, this would be doable as a plugin if you wished (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/file_objects.html). Or, if you can wait, this is definitely the sort of API we'd offer ourselves if there was sufficient interest.

Comment: Thanks James. It definitely seems like there should be enough interest. I haven't come across too many apps that don't offer the standard sharing button.

Comment: James do you have a feature voting-list or wish-list somewhere?